# White page until scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

I am working on this site: http://www.nuriteldar.co.il.

And I have a strange problem, when the page loads on mobile it shows a white page until you scroll.

I tried to chack it by safe mode in "device toolbar" in chrome DevTools and it not shows any effect in css.

What can it be? And, how can I solve it?

P.S if you switch to another page after you scroll it also show white page until you scroll

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's working for my side

[image: See Image]

Otherwise you can clear browser cache and cookies. and check later.